# Find Individuals who have purchased 10 times within a rolling 1 year period

Tags: sql, postgresql

So let's say I have 2 tables. One table is for consumers, and another is for sales.

**Consumers**

| ID | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Johns | ... |
| 2 | Cathy Dans | ... |

**Sales**

| ID | consumer_id | purchase_date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/03/05 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 02/04/10 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | 03/04/11 | ... |
| 4 | 2 | 02/14/07 | ... |
| 5 | 2 | 09/24/08 | ... |
| 6 | 2 | 12/15/09 | ... |

I want to find all instances of consumers who made more than 10 purchases within any 6 month rolling period.

```
SELECT
    consumers.id
        , COUNT(sales.id)
  FROM
      consumers
          JOIN sales ON consumers.id = sales.consumer_id
 GROUP BY
     consumers.id
HAVING
    COUNT(sales.id) >= 10
 ORDER BY
     COUNT(sales.id) DESC
```

So I have this code, which just gives me a list of consumers who have made more than 10 purchases ALL TIME. But how do I incorporate the rolling 6 month period logic?!

Any help or guidance on which functions can help me accomplish this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to count the number of sales in a six-month period.  Then just filter down to those consumers:

```
select distinct consumer_id
from (select s.*,
             count(*) over (partition by consumer_id 
                            order by purchase_date
                            range between current row and interval '6 month' following
                           ) as six_month_count
      from sales s
     ) s
where six_month_count > 10;
```